# Editing Maui premade classes

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I would like to use the OnNavigatedFrom function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom?view=net-maui-8.0) to unregister event listeners that are no longer in use. But I would like to decide when to turn them off depending on which page is navigated to. The function has a NavigatedFromEventArgs args that includes in it the destination, but the variable is internal (not public) so I don't have access to it.

I am quite new as a developer so I would like to know what is recommended to do in this scenario, is it fine for me to edit this already built in Maui class? Make the variable from internal to public? Or should I just find another way to do it? In what cases should one edit those kind of classes?

I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO and to your exciting development journey. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve, ideally by including relevant bits of code in the question and, if necessary, by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you're stuck with a specific problem. As for your question: You cannot modify classes that come from third-party libraries.

Comment: You probably can't manually change the access modifiers from internal to public. Also, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post.

Comment: It might be better if I explain what I want to do rather than how I thought I could solve it. Lets say I have those pages (the arrow represents the navigation): MainPage <-> File <-> Info (can't navigate from Info to MainPage). When the user goes to File, a WeakReferenceMessenger is registered in File, which is meant to receive messages from Info. If the user navigates to Info from Page, the WRM is still meant to be on, meanwhile when he navigates back to MainPage it is meant to be unregistered. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, it is not necessary to unregister the WeakReferenceMessenger type because when recipients are unused they are eligible for garbage collection. But it is good practice to unregister them for better performance. You can try to unregister it in the constructor of  MainPage.

Answer (score 1):

you need to [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) the method

```
override protected void OnNavigatedFrom (NavigatedFromEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.SomeProperty == SomeValue)
    {
        // do stuff here
    }

    base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done that, the problem is that the args property is defines as internal so I don't have access to it.

Comment: there is nothing in the docs saying it is `internal`.  What specifically are you trying to do and what specific error or problem occurs?

Comment: In my C# code behind of a content page I would like to use the function OnNavigatedFrom to call on a function of in my viewmodel (that is bound to it) to unregister WeakReferenceMessenger. Such that when the user leaves the page it will turn off the unnecessary listeners.  But there are some pages that when the user navigates to I would like the listeners to be still on. So basically I would like to do an if statement in which if(args.Destination == TestPage){....}.

Comment: I go into the definition of NavigatedFromEventArgs args, and it only contains a single property called Destination, that property is internal. There was another person working on this code before but he said that he didn't change anything. Also if it is not internal what is it then? There is nothing about it I can find in documentation.